# Vectorize image drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, pixel, trace

There is image, that loaded from server, that I draw on canvas.
Image is 2 color, and there is polygon drawing on it,
0 - transparent color(no color) and yellow.

How to trace boundaries of polygon?
I know, that it is realy difficult question. Moore Neighborhood. is only one think that i have found.

Comment: https://github.com/epistemex/msqr

Comment: @K3N's [msqr](https://github.com/epistemex/msqr)  is a nicely improved version of the Marching Squares Algorithm which is an algorithm that finds path points along the perimeter of a shape. His version also includes a path simplification routine to reduce the count of points on the path.

Answer (score 0):

javascript has no good performance to deal with image arrays, and for this reason is hard do find frameworks to do complex image detections. I suggest you to use a [strong and low level image framework](http://opencv.org/) in your server side (upload pic to your server and just send back the results in numbers). If you need to draw your poligon, you can use svg graphics, they are fully compatible with most browsers and very easy to write in vector.
Here is something about get image boundaries:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0